# angular.min.js:118 Error: [ng:areq]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm starting learning Angular.js with this book "Angular.js OReilly", I am trying to construct the first examples that they have. I already downloaded Angular.js from the website and create my controller.js like it says, but I always get the error in the title.

This is what I did:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller='HelloController'>
        <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

function HelloController($scope) {
console.log("a");
$scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
}
```

Comment: You must be using latest version of Angular which may not be supporting this syntax to create controller.

Comment: well, what you advice me?, i want to follow the book, maybe install the previous version? or migrate to the new version and follow some tutorials??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using so old syntax? Try to start with new syntax you can do your above requirement like below code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);//creating app

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) { // creating controller
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="GreetingController">
  {{ greeting }}
</div>
</body>
```

First you have to make app then make a controller. try this

Comment: yeah i already solved it, i just used old syntax cause i was following a book, maybe i need to search another book that uses the new syntax do you know anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put HelloController between  tag inside  tag.

```
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
<script>
function HelloController($scope) {
console.log("a");
$scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: i have the function HelloController inside the controllers.js

Comment: can you please share controller.js with us ?